# Unnecessary to add title on ALL links?

Tags: html, seo, title

I know some SEO, but I have to ask:

Is it unnecessary to add title on a link if there is no optimisation for that word or page (for example a link to a "contact page", wich I don't bother to rank high on Google). Or does google some how value that all links have title?

```
<a href="/contact" title="Unnecessary title">Click here to contact us</a>
<a href="/contact">Click here to contact us</a>
```

**My thought is:**

Only add title when

a) You want to help the page rank on google.

or

b) If you care about the yellow little hover-message.

Comment: A note would be that I'm writing the code in pure HTML :)

Comment: Such SEO is bogus. Work on producing *good content* and use appropriate markup where it makes sense. And read this [recent news story](http://tech.slashdot.org/story/12/03/18/1831231/google-is-planning-to-penalize-overly-optimized-sites).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Whether or not a link has a `title` applied is nearly irrelevant to SEO or little yellow hover messages (commonly known as tooltips). It's about semantics and meaningful content. Basically:

```
<a href="/contact" title="free good software here find great stuff stupid idiotic keyword overload">Click here to contact us</a>
```

is a *really* terrible thing to do. `title` is meant to summarize the content of the link, but you don't need it if the content of the element accurately summarizes it on its own, as yours does. Putting identical content in both is also redundant.

A general rule of thumb: put `title` on a link when you need to describe it more. For example:

```html
... or <a href="/contact" title="Contact us">get more information about the product</a>.
```

Accessible and clean. *Don't* add a `title` attribute if you only want it for SEO.

Answer (score 2):

An interesting approach :

http://www.searchenginejournal.com/how-to-use-link-title-attribute-correctly/7687/

> (...)
>
> *A couple of years ago, Googlers confirmed they did not use TITLE
>   attribute in the algorithm because it was used too seldom. This has
>   changes since then but I still **failed to spot any evidence that link
>   TITLE attribute somehow influenced the rankings** (you can run a simple
>   test: include any non-existent word – that doesn’t exist in Google
>   index – as a link title, wait for the link to be indexed, and in some
>   time check if either the linking or linked page got ranked for that
>   word).*
>   (...)
>
> **Conclusions on TITLE attribute usage:**
>
> - use it for your users, not search engines (this approach always pays back);
> - don’t duplicate it with link text (this hurts usability: for example some blind users will hear the same text twice);
> - don’t put too much weight on the title attributes as not all screenreaders may render it (make sure either surrounding text or
>     anchor text explains the link at least the first time you use it).
>
> (...)

Answer (score 1):

I don't think Google cares much about the title. I believe it just uses the text inside the anchor to identify the link. The title is just so the user can get additional information when they hover over it. If you don't want Google to follow or index it, use `rel="nofollow"`.

So no, if the title provides no additional information, don't use it.