# When focus leaves all child links in a div, fire an event

Tags: javascript, jquery, accessibility

I'm working on allowing keyboard only users to navigate my menu. When a user clicks on a link, a panel opens showing the menu. A user can tab through the links fine, but when the user gets to the end of the menu and focus is on the next element, the previous menu closes.

See example: http://codepen.io/AdamWills/pen/Ejstd

Obviously my focusout function doesn't work properly, but I'm not sure how to do this properly.

Any ideas?

HTML:

```
<div>
  <p><a class="open" href="#">Open menu 1</a></p>
  <div class="panel hidden">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>

<div>
  <p><a class="open" href="#">Open menu 2</a></p>
    <div class="panel hidden">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
 </div>

<p><a href="#">Next Link</a></p>
```

JS:

```
$('.open').on('click', function() {
  $(this).parent().parent().find('.panel').toggleClass('hidden');
});

$('.panel').on('focusout',function() {
  $(this).addClass('hidden');
});
```

EDIT: This is not my production HTML - just a quick example of the basic structure I'm working with.

Comment: Linking to an external resource for your code sample is taboo on SO - please include the code in question.

Comment: to be more specific: linking to codepen or jsbin or jsfiddle etc. to show a working example is perfectly fine, but you should also put the code that is relevant to your problem in your question.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know. I've included the code in the OP.

Comment: HTML5 note: html has had a `<button>` element to do what you're using `<a href="#">` for since html 3.2. Under modern HTML rules, `href='#'` means "navigate to the top of the page", whereas you want to use it as a click/enter handler. Good idea to stop incorrectly using link anchors for that purpose. (and it only looks like a button until you give it CSS that makes it look what you need. A button is just an element with a border and extra hover/active rules)

Answer (score 1):

A couple problems I notice reviewing your code. Some you might be aware of, others will require some research on your end.

- HTML semantics
- <s>SEO titles</s>
- CSS

To solve your issue(s) nest your submenu's, use proper title attributes for usability and make sure your CSS is marked up to capture the mouse events to keep this functionality as well.

**HTML**

```
<ul>
    <li class="open">
        <a href="javascript:void(0);" title="Open menu 1"><span>Open menu 1</span></a>
        <ul class="panel hidden">
            <li><a href="#">Menu 1 Link 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Menu 1 Link 2</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="open">
        <a href="javascript:void(0);" title="Open menu 2"><span>Open menu 2</span></a>
        <ul class="panel hidden">
            <li><a href="#">Menu 2 Link 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Menu 2 Link 2</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="open">
        <a href="javascript:void(0);" title="Open menu 3"><span>Open menu 3</span></a>
        <ul class="panel hidden">
            <li><a href="#">Menu 3 Link 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Menu 3 Link 2</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Additionally to the nesting of submenu's you can use an HTML `nav` element. Don't use hash `#` in the `href` to make sure the page doesn't jump up. I've added spans to the anchor tags so you have more options in CSS. <s>Use the title attributes for usability (screen readers, SEO, ...)</s>.

**CSS**

```
ul { display: block; }
ul li { background-color: grey; display: block; float: left; position: relative; }
ul li ul { background-color: darkgrey; display: block; position: absolute; top: 3.2em; left: 0; margin: 0; padding: 0; }
ul li ul li { display: block; }

a { color: white; display: block; padding: 1em; }
a:focus,
a:hover{ color: red; }
```

I've changed the markup a bit to make sure hover events are captured on the parent elements AND the children. If there's space in between you will trigger extra `mouseleave` events. In that case it doesn't work. Therefor the semantic HTML can help using `position:relative` for the parent menu's and `position: absolute` for the children.
Also note I've added the `a:hover` to keep similar behavior.

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
$('ul').on('focusin mouseenter', 'li', function() {
    var el = $(this),
        panels = $('.panel'),
        menu = el.parents('.open'),
        menuId = menu.index(),
        sub = el.find('ul');

    // conditionally hide the submenu when using focus
    if (menuId < 0){
        panels.addClass('hidden'); // use a filter function to improve it
    }

    sub.removeClass('hidden');
});

$('ul').on('focusout mouseleave', 'li', function(ev){
    var el = $(this),
        itemId = el.index(),
        menu = el.parents('.open'),
        menuId = menu.index(),
        sub = el.find('ul');

    // conditionally hide the submenu when using the mouse
    if (menuId < 0 && ev.type !== 'focusout'){
        sub.addClass('hidden');
    }
});
```

On the JavaScript part I'm sure you want to keep mouse functionality. In that case we can use `focusin mouseenter` and `focusout mouseleave` as suggested by Pomax earlier. The trick I've used is to capture the event type to see whether we are using a keyboard or a mouse. Both event bindings were acting a bit differently so that solves this particular problem. The `index()` of a jQuery object can help to determine whether you are on a submenu or a menu item. A simple trick to do different things when the index can't be found or is `-1`.

What I haven't done is checked if it's crossbrowser compatible. Also on the javascript part I believe some events are fired too often. Maybe it's not a good idea to use delegates `on()` in this case unless your list items are dynamically added to the page.

Hope it helps, good luck finetuning this!

**DEMO**
http://jsfiddle.net/tive/vkQ3v/

Comment: +1 but not sure adding tittle attributes is useful (esp. if it's the same text that's contained in the links. The title attribute isn't reliably announced by screenreaders and pretty much all attributes are ignored by search engines (thanks to pollution by SEO hacks.)

Comment: Based on recent AnySurfer reviews we've had I tend to keep them in. SEO has recently changed on this matter then? Damn! Worth to look into, thanks.

Comment: Thanks for bursting my bubble steveax
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9833042/unnecessary-to-add-title-on-all-links

Answer (score 0):

You can give your elements a `tabindex` to make sure they get tabbed to in the correct order without requiring any code (same tabindex means tab through them in declared sequence). You can then give each of them an onfocus handler that does `element.show()` and an onblur to effect `element.hide()`, and simply keep the wrapper an inert wrapper. That way if your users tab into the element, it shows up, they hit tab, the browser finds the next tabbable element based on tabindex, onblur fires on the old element and onfocus fires on the new element.

That said, buttons already have a tabindex, but have a look at http://codepen.io/anon/pen/KesbI

Comment: Currently the tab order isn't an issue. It's important for the layout for the panel to show/hide... not sure how I can implement this solution in my example.

Comment: You use the `tabindex` mostly just so that the browser now treats your elements as tabbable to/from, automatically firing onfocus and onblur respectively.

Comment: added a working example codepen.io doing what I gathered you needed it to do from your post.